# Find startdate of a week from last year in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

We assume that the week starts from Mon and ends  at Sunday. 
While trying to comparing with last year, how can we get the right dates? 
For example, if i want to compare this week (10/23/2017 to 10/29/2017) with  year same week (10/24/2016 to 10/30/2016)

I am setting 2 parameters in SSRS BeginDate and BeginDateLastYear .  The value of BeginDate = 10/23/2017
How can i assume the value for BeginDateLastYear as a value precisely to the Monday of same week number in last year ( IN this case it should be 10/24/2016) ?

Currently i am trying to set the value of StartDate in last year like

```
BeginDateLastYear =DATEADD(DateInterval.Year,-1,Parameters!BeginDate.Value)
```

Also i tried to use

```
 =DATEADD(DateInterval.Week,-52,Parameters!BeginDate.Value) , but not very sure will this work precisely to same week start date of last year
```

Comment: It depends on user requirements. From my perspective in any case you should compare full weeks. So the question is what do you do in extreme cases of week1/week53 when for example week1 of 2017 has 7 days while the same week of 2016 has only 2? (use week2 of 2016 instead or use last 5 days of 2015 with the 2 of 2016)

Comment: week 1 /53 is permitted  exceptions for us   . The importance is from week 2 to week 52 only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reporting services you can use the following expression for BeginDateLastYear

```
= DATEADD(
    DateInterval.WeekOfYear, 
    IIF( 
        DATEPART(DateInterval.WeekOfYear,DATEADD(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, -52   ,  Parameters!BeginDate.Value))<> DATEPART(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, Parameters!BeginDate.Value) , 
        -53, 
        -52 
        ) ,  
    Parameters!BeginDate.Value
    )
```

**Code logic:**

If by going back 52 weeks the two week numbers do not match go back 53 weeks, else go back 52 weeks

In case you want to implement it in SQL without using the second parameter (SSRS has some issues on cascading parameters)

```
SET @BeginDateLastYear = 
    DATEADD(
        wk, 
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(wk,DATEADD(wk, -52   , @BeginDate))<> DATEPART(wk,@BeginDate) 
            THEN -53 
            ELSE -52 END, 
        @BeginDate
            )
```

Comment: HOw can we make sure the BeginDateLastYear is a Monday (so make sure all days from Monday to Sunday is getting covered)

Comment: If BeginDate user selection is monday, BeginDateLastYear will also be monday